# Generating dynamic list with json response

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a json array like following;

```
"collectings": [
    {
      "hint": "OPEN",
      "amount": 24
    },
    {
      "hint": "CREDIT CARD",
      "amount": 347
    },
    {
      "hint": "CASH",
      "amount": 256.5
    }
  ]
```

Now, I want to display this data on a list dynamically, I am trying to do it like following;

```
<ion-content>
<div class="row" *ngIf="collectings && collectings.length > 0">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>Comedy</ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let collecting of collectings">{{collectings}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

but, it is displayed on the page like the below image;
[image]
How can I display it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `{{ collectings }}` (which is the array)

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let collecting of collectings">{{collectings}}</ion-item>
```

you should print the `collecting` property (without the ending s) and use the `hint` or `amount` sub-properties like this:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let collecting of collectings">
   {{collecting.hint}} - {{ collecting.amount }}
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: @sebaferreas I have already tried it but, when I do that it displays nothing. I have already checked the array is empty or not with the ngIf part because, I am getting array as response from rest and bind it to my array.

Comment: @sebaferreas yeah you are right. I was printing the collectings. Now, its working